# How to get only 1 result from a table that contain this value more than once?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

I have a table that looks like:

```
ID     Name    Location
1      peter   New York
2      john    New York
3      jack    New York
4      shaun   London
```

As you see the Location Column values maybe the same for many users , How can I get only one result from each Location on searching for New York for example?

I'm using these SQL queries:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * from users WHERE location SOUNDS LIKE  :s');
$stmt->bindValue(':s', '%' . $query . '%' , PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$values = $stmt->fetchAll();

$count = $stmt->rowCount();
if($count > 0){
    foreach($values as $val){
        echo $val['location'];
    }
}
```

**Please notice :**
I don't want to use `LIMIT 1` because it's for a search form and there would be another locations the the user may want to view like Newcastle on entering new.

Is it possible this way or I need to create another table with **one to many** relationship with the users table?

Comment: Which one do you want?

Comment: @GordonLinoff , It's for a searching form so it could be any location and this location maybe exist more than once , I just want to show one from each duplicated location

Comment: @Syscall , Is there is something wrong about using it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE ID IN (SELECT MIN(id)
             FROM users
             WHERE location SOUNDS LIKE  :s
             GROUP BY location
            );
```

Comment: and all the other functions would remain the same ?                          
`$stmt->bindValue(':s', '%' . $query . '%' , PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$values = $stmt->fetchAll();`

Comment: @peter . . . This would return one row for each location, the one with the lowest `id`.